# How to remove user defined line in a file using batch script

Tags: file, batch-file, notepad++, notepad, batch-rename

I would like to remove specific line in a file using a batch script.

Here' my scenario, For example I have a .txt file named "Files.txt".

When you open Files.txt. it contains list of files. For example:

```
Name     Sample1.txt       Sample2.txt
Age      Age1.txt          Age2.txt
```

When you open Sample1.txt, here's the sample content:

```
SET AAAAA
GET BBBBB
MOV CCCCC
COP DDDDD
```

Now, I would like the user to have the option which part of the line he would like to remove in Sample1.txt file. For example:

```
Enter the line/s you want to remove (separated by comma): SET,MOV
```

After this, the content of the Sample.txt file will be:

```
GET BBBBB
COP DDDDD
```

Basically, if we call Files.txt, the column 2 and 3 will be compared.

```
for /f "tokens=2,3" %%a in ('type c:\sample\files.txt') do (
echo Comparing Column 2: %%a  Column 3: %%b 
rem Logic for comparison goes here
```

Now, before comaparing, I want the user to have the option to remove lines in a file the he dont want to include in the comparison.

Note that I already have the logic for the comparing column 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Remove line script

```
 @echo off

 For /f "tockens=1-2 delims= " %%a in (nameoffile.txt) do (

 Set /p line= enter line to remove :

 If not "%%a"=="!line!" (

 Echo >nameoffile.txt

 Echo %%a %%b >> nameoffile.txt

         )

 )
```

Nameoffle should be the same in set collection in for loop and echo at if statement so the batch file could overwrite the original file

Place batch file on same directory as text file

Comment: mordecai

For example I have nameoffile.txt that contains filenames. What if I still want the original files names of files contain in nameoffile.txt?